# Where did they find the storm troopers for the original Star Wars trilogy movies?

Tags: star-wars, actors, actor-identification

Does anyone know how they filled the cast for all the storm troopers in the original trilogy (IV, V, VI) movies.  Did they get them from military volunteers?

[image: Darth Vader, accompanied by Imperial officers, strides between the massed ranks of Stormtroopers, Death Star troopers and other Imperials]

Comment: Are you asking about the out-of-universe extras or the in-universe soldiers?

Comment: I'm asking about the original trilogy casting

Comment: There's really only probably about a dozen actual actors used for storm troopers. The masses you see in shots like that are just matte paintings.

Comment: @phantom42 could you add that as an answer with maybe some link to wiki and I'll mark as answer :D

Comment: [Example](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-HIfafsbO8zU/UXyAO98SM9I/AAAAAAAAPpk/k9Su4p2DvQk/s1600/68.jpg)

Comment: @phantom42 - Awesome. This needs to be an answer.

Comment: Sure. Let me dig up some more examples and I'll post something.

Comment: @phantom42 - You'd best hurry. My trigger-finger is itching now that I've seen that photo... :-)

Comment: @phantom42 I suggest you just post the picture and I'll mark it then add extra info after the publish

Comment: In a similar fashion, very few actual birds were used when filing *The Birds*.

Comment: There's a *Kamino* island in Pacific Ocean...

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In actuality, there's probably only about a dozen or so actors used for Stormtroopers (lots of actors are reused, like [Jeremy Bulloch](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0120116/) appearing in ESB as both Boba Fett and an unmasked Imperial Officer)

Most of the vast legions of Stormtroopers are created utilizing [matte paintings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matte_painting).

Wikipedia explains:

> A matte painting is a painted representation of a landscape, set, or distant location that allows filmmakers to create the illusion of an environment that is nonexistent in real life or would otherwise be too expensive or impossible to build or visit. Historically, matte painters and film technicians have used various techniques to combine a matte-painted image with live-action footage. At its best, depending on the skill levels of the artists and technicians, the effect is "seamless" and creates environments that would otherwise be impossible to film.

Here is one in-progress

[image: matte painting in progress: the painter, standing to the right, uses a white brush to add Stormtrooper to the left end of a rank]

Here is a finished one. If you look closely, you can see a "black" area near the shuttle. That's a clear spot on the glass where the live action would be filmed through. Watch closely in scenes where there are large groups of troops, and you'll notice that only those closest to the action ever actually move. That's because they're the only ones that were real actors.

[Here is a great explanation of the history and some of the "hows" of matte painting](https://design.tutsplus.com/articles/the-history-of-matte-painting-basix--psd-10322)

> Norman Dawn developed a technique that joined together a Photograph and a Painting to enhance the environment that is being shot by the camera (Wikipedia). Dawn, a photographer himself, took his photos and paintings and placed them on a large sheet of glass. Black tape was then placed over the parts of the camera where the painting would go. After the camera was positioned properly the live action scene would take place. What resulted was a union between a simple painting and actual live scenery.

[image: finished painting: the Imperial Shuttle rests in a docking bay, surrounded by blocks of Imperial troops in formation; a large black area extends from beneath the shuttle out in front]

[image: a painter with his work: a partially-completed view of the Millennium Falcon from A New Hope looking down on the docking bay]

Did you really think they built a village in the trees?

[image: Did you really think they built a village in the trees?]

Not specifically Star Wars, but a great example of the steps involved in using a matte painting

[image: an early example of matte painting]

Here is an artist setting up the camera so that it only films the live-action portions of the scene

[image: an artist sets up the camera]

Here is a great example of what is filmed actually filmed versus the final shot

[image: The matte painting versus the set]

Let's put it all together to see what it looks like.

Wookieepedia has [some more matte paintings here](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Matte_paintings) and [Gizmodo has a great feature: *The matte paintings of the original Star Wars trilogy and their creators*](https://sploid.gizmodo.com/the-amazing-matte-paintings-from-star-wars-and-their-cr-1680372651)

---

As for how the actual troopers/actors *did* get cast...

I haven't actually read anything from an actual Stormtrooper, but based on what I *have* read and heard, I imagine it was the typical process for being cast as an non-featured role: know someone or get the job through the standard extra casting process.

Jeremy Bulloch said in [an interview](https://www.vanityfair.com/online/oscars/2010/10/boba-fett-talks-about-the-empire-strikes-back-that-crazy-suit-and-the-star-wars-legacy):

> Did you have to audition for Boba Fett?
>
> No, I’ve said before, if I hadn’t fit in the outfit, I wouldn’t have played the part. There was only one costume. My half-brother, Robert Watts, was an associate producer and he said, “Look, get your agent on to this. It’s not very much, but you never know.” So I went back and put the outfit on. And that was the interview with producer Gary Kurtz, putting bits of the outfit on and it fit like a glove. I always say to people, “It was meant to be.”

Having gone through the extra-casting process myself in the past, typically casting agencies are provided general descriptions of roles/groups they're looking for. Each candidate either provides a few basic photos, or comes in for them (as I had to). Those who fit the descriptions may be called in for fittings or readings if necessary. In my case, I was chosen solely on my appearance since it was for "deep background" where I would only be yelling and looking angry (for Pirates of the Caribbean 2 and 3).

For roles like Storm Troopers and most Rebels, a similar process would have occurred.

Comment: What? And here I was hoping that all the Star Wars movies had been filmed on location.

Comment: @Xantec - "No ewoks were harmed in the filming of this episode"

Comment: @Richard - A Jar-Jar Binks was harmed in the filming of this episode. Repeatedly.

Comment: @DVK - My fave video; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLACxMXBRhM

Comment: Essentially, low-tech CGI

Comment: "Watch closely in scenes where there are large groups of troops, and you'll notice that only those closest to the action ever actually move. That's because they're the only ones that were real actors." No! Storm Troopers are just very well trained.

Comment: Can you replace the "video unavailable"? It's the one under "Let's put it all together to see what it looks like."

Answer (score 12):

As per phantom42's answer, this was the days just before CGI, so there were a few live actors composited onto small live-action windows in matte paintings by these painters:

**Star Wars**: [Ralph McQuarrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_McQuarrie) and [Mike Pangrazio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Pangrazio)

**Empire Strikes Back**: Harrison Ellenshaw, Ralph McQuarrie, Mike Pangrazio

**Return of the Jedi**: Mike Pangrazio, Chris Evans, Frank Ordaz

Pictures:

- http://makingfx.net/archives/1241
- http://www.harrisonellenshaw.com/bts1.html
- https://markwestwriter.blogspot.com/2013/10/return-of-jedi-matte-paintings.html

Comment: A good post but I feel that much of this could have been added as an edit to the accepted answer.

Comment: @Richard: the identities of the matte painters needed to be called out. Their skill is amazing and it has died out due to CGI.

Comment: Matte painting has *not* died out due to CGI. Mattes are now less frequently used in traditional filming, but even CG scenes still employ matte paintings for backgrounds.

Answer (score 7):

In addittion to matte paintings, cardboard figures were also used, notably in the hangar scenes in Return and the ceremony at Yavin.

If you have the old editions, you see this if you look for it, but I'm pretty sure this was replaced in the newer, more CG versions.

Edit:
Here is a link to two photos from the award ceremony at [forum.blu-ray.com](https://forum.blu-ray.com/showpost.php?p=5164434&postcount=27850). However, it is easier to see in the film as the cardboard cutouts are 100% stationary whilst live actors usually move somewhat no matter how still they should be (and CG characters usually move more unnaturally).

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF.SE! This is a good answer that adds content to the other one. However, it would be great if you could add some source other than "look at the old editions and see by yourself". Enjoy your experience on this site :)

Comment: In the link, the two photos do not show. Best to have copied them here.

Comment: These photos appear to have been taken down at the source; this answer needs fixing up.

Comment: Here is a link to show the cardboard cut out use at the end of Episode IV, and its replacement in the update. https://i.imgur.com/7m1eVcs.png / https://i.imgur.com/C4aOWw7.png (the 2011 label is wrong, the change was in the 97 Special Edition)

Answer (score 5):

They were all supplied by Central Casting in London, akin to its sister union in Los Angeles. This agency no longer exists.

I was one of the originals.

Comment: You were one of the originals? That is fantastic!